# Calculate incremental weighted mean and covariance in python

Tags: python, numpy

I've been trying to implement an incremental weighted mean and covariance calculator. So given a data matrix X of size `(N,D)` and weights of size `(N,)`, I need to be able to get its weighted statistics (mean vector of size `(D,)`) and covariance matrix of size `(D,D)`) by running `update` in the class below

I've gotten the weighted mean part but I'm unsure how to proceed with calculating the covariance matrix in this manner.

```
import numpy as np

class OnlineWeightStats:
    def __init__(self, X):
        N, D = X.shape
        self.data_mat = X
        self.mean = np.zeros(D)
        self.wsum = 1e-7

    def update(self, weights=None):
        if weights is None:
            weights = np.ones(self.data_mat.shape[0])     
        for d, w in zip(self.data_mat,weights):
            self.wsum += w
            upcon = (w / self.wsum)
            delta = d - self.mean
            self.mean += delta * upcon

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 10000
    D = 2
    X = np.random.rand(N,D)

    # Define OnlineStats
    ows = OnlineWeightStats(X)
    # Update 1
    ows.update() # No weights, so just calculates standard mean

    # Change weights and update again
    new_weights = np.random.uniform(0,1,N)
    ows.update(new_weights)

    # Change weights and update 
    ......
```

Comment: does [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/71275) question on stats stackexchange answer your question? let me know if you have trouble implementing it, I can do that sometime later as I need something similar in python

Comment: It's helpful but at the moment my problem is the implementation. The link talks about weighted covariance which  can be solved using ```np.cov(X, rowvar=False, aweights=weights)``` for X of shape (N,D). The confusing bit for me is the incremental weighting.

Comment: Could you explain the _incremental_ part? I don't see any _incremental_ formulation in the expression

Comment: By incremental I mean the mean, covariance and total number of weights (wsum) are incrementally updated  (by looping over the data matrix) with every call of the update function. I believe this is called method of provisional means as mentioned in this [link](http://www.pmean.com/04/ProvisionalMeans.html#:~:text=It%20relies%20on%20an%20algorithm,in%20the%20data%20set%20appears.).

Comment: I've added some more details to the code snippet illustrating its usage.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I get it now. I will update it I figure it out! hopefully, I can give it a try tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution. I'm thinking this is the best that Python (with numpy) can do unless we count writing it as a C/C++ extension.

```
import numpy as np

class OnlineWeightStats:
    def __init__(self, X):
        N, D = X.shape
        self.data_mat = X
        self.mean = np.zeros(D)
        self.wsum = 1e-7
        self.xpsum = np.zeros((D,D)) # Sum of cross-products

    def update(self, weights=None):
        if weights is None:
            weights = np.ones(self.data_mat.shape[0])     
        for d, w in zip(self.data_mat,weights):
            self.wsum += w
            upcon = (w / self.wsum)
            delta = d - self.mean

            # Weighted mean computation
            self.mean += delta * upcon
            # Weighted covariance computation
            self.xpsum += np.outer(delta, delta) * w * (1-upcon)

        self.cov = self.xpsum/self.wsum
```